# How to add a foreign key with onUpdate Cascade in an M2 installer script?

Tags: magento2, database, installer

I want to add a table with a foreign key in an installer script. 
The foreign key should have

ONDELETE CASCADE **and** ONUPDATE CASCADE set, - but the ->addForeignKey method supports only the ONDELETE one.

How can I set the ONUPDATE CASCADE setting?

My code:

```php
$table = $installer->getConnection()
            ->newTable($installer->getTable('my_new_table'))
            ->addColumn(
                'entity_id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
                11,
                ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => false, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
                'Entity ID'
            )
            ->addColumn(
                'store_id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_SMALLINT,
                5,
                ['nullable' => false, 'unsigned' => true, 'primary' => true],
                'Store ID'
            )
->addForeignKey(
                'fk_entity_store_id',
                'entity_id',
                'my_new_table',
                'entity_id',
                \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::ACTION_CASCADE
            );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ONUPDATE CASCADE is executed, when the row id of a record is changed. This should not happen in Magento at all, as the ids are unique and persistent over their lifetime. Actions like the change of a row id should be prevented from occurring.

Luckily, this is exactly, what omitting an ONUPDATE clause does:

> RESTRICT: Rejects the delete or update operation for the parent table. Specifying RESTRICT (or NO ACTION) is the same as omitting the ON DELETE or ON UPDATE clause. 
>   (Source:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html:)

The "missing" parameter has therefore most likely been omitted by design.